# Dispatch credentials store.dispatch(new Login(userName, password))

Tags: angular, authentication, ngrx, ngrx-effects

What is the best way of dispatching a sensitive information through ngrx-store? For example, when we dispatch a sensitive credential information like "store.dispatch(new Login(userName, password))" the credentials will be visible in the ngrx-dev tools which seems a security flaw. Is there any best practice to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

The store devtools is a local plugin, so you will only see your credentials.

In a production environment it's possible to not include the devtools:

```
environment.production 
 ? []
 : StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      name: 'NgRx Book Store App',
   }),
```

Comment: Thank you Tim for the answer. In fact, I realized that I have an option not to reflect credentials to the state through effect. So we're good.